# Question of current with multiple current sources

Tags: current, current-source, current-divider

Suppose we have this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fntg1d.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My question is this:How much is the current from I1 through R1? I guess it is 500mA because I2 is an open circuit from the point of view of I1 and R1=R2 so the current from I2 is shared equally between the 2 resistance. But i have found some videos on youtube which say it is 250mA because I2 is 500mA so the rest current which flow through R1 and R2 must be equal to 500mA and again since R1=R2 the currents are shared equally from the resistors.I am asking this because I got confused.Any help appreciated!

Comment: Can you write a KCL equation for all of the currents entering or leaving the top node? That, plus the knowledge that the two resistors are in parallel, should give you the answer.

Comment: Could you clarify: is your question asking about the **total** current through R1? Or are you asking from the perspective of [superposition](https://ultimateelectronicsbook.com/superposition/), considering each source (I1 and I2) individually?

Comment: 250 mA. 500 mA will be shared.

Comment: I2 removes half the current from I1 away from the two resistors.

Comment: my question is about the the current through R1 only from I1.

Comment: How should we know which electrons are from I1 and which are from I2?

Comment: Let me put it another way electrons from I1 wont pas through I2 correct?

Comment: Incorrect Miss Mulan.

Comment: Replace the resistors with a 50 ohm resistor.

Comment: Andy how is that incorrect since a current source has infinite resistance?

Comment: @Miss Mulan, just one clarification. The current source I2 has a very high "differential resistance" (only when the voltage across it changes); it is not an open circuit. In this DC mode, the voltage is constant (12.5 V) and as much as 500mA flows through I2. So its "static" (DC) resistance is only 12.5/0.5 = 25 ohms.

Comment: The voltage across a current source will self-adjust to whatever voltage is required to pass its rated current. As i2 is a 500 mA source it WILL source 500 mA. In this case, as it is "upside down" relative to i1 it will SINK 500mA from i1. The other 500 mA will pass through the resistors.

Comment: @Russell McMahon♦, What does "urgent source" mean here? I have not met it as an expression...

Comment: @Circuitfantasist Thanks. Typo. Corrected (a moderator privilege :-) ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Visualization

Here is a picture with visualized currents and voltage(s) that can help understanding.

[image: Visualized currents and voltages]

Fig. 1. Visualized currents and voltages

*Current paths* are represented by closed thick lines (loops) in green whose thickness is proportional to the current magnitude. *Voltage drops* are represented by vertical lines (bars) in red whose height is proportional to the voltage value. They are the same since the four elements are connected in parallel.

### Operation

Here is a possible intuitive explanation of the operation.

The two current sources try to pass their currents contrary through the two resistors - I1 from top to bottom and I2 from bottom to top. In this "struggle", I1 prevails and passes half of its current (500 mA) through the resistors that is distributed evenly (250 mA) between them (current divider). As a result, the upper ends of the resistors become positive and the lower ends - negative.

I2 seeks a path for its current and finds it through I1 by absorbing a half of its current (500 mA). The voltage across I2 has an opposite polarity; so it may not contain an internal voltage source (*dynamic resistor* only).

### Application

The benefit of such fictional electrical circuits becomes greater if we can show their applications in electronic circuits. In this case, this is the circuit of an op-amp inverting amplifier.

[image: Op-amp inverting ampifier- conceptual circuit]

Fig. 2. Op-amp inverting ampifier - conceptual circuit

**Structure.** Here, I1 (input) current source is represented by Vin-R1 network and I2 (output) current source - by R2-Vout network (R1 and R2 are the inverting amplifier's resistors). The resistors from the OP's diagram are connected in parallel to the op-amp differential input. One of them can be the op-amp input resistance, the other - some leakage.

**Operation.** In this configuration, I2 current source is controlled by the voltage drop across the parallel resistors as follows.

*Ideal op-amp.* The op-amp adjusts its output voltage so that to make its differential input voltage (almost) zero (*virtual ground*). As a result, it sinks (diverts) all the input current... and there is no current flowing through the parallel resistors. The common current Iin = Vin/R1 = Vout/R2 = Iout flows only through both current sources. The output voltage is Vout = -Vin.R2/R1.

*Real op-amp.* If the op-amp has insufficient gain, Vout < Vin.R2/R1. A positive voltage drop will appear across the parallel resistors and a part of the input current will be diverted through them. The virtual ground will move inside R2. This is the OP's case.

*Over-acting op-amp.* Now imagine the most interesting case when the op-amp "over-acts" and produces a voltage more than needed - Vout > Vin.R2/R1. We can make it behave in such a weird way by introducing a small positive feedback in addition to the existing negative feedback. For this purpose, let's connect another voltage divider R3-R4 between the op-amp output and the non-inverting input. The positive voltage drop at the inverting input will become negative; hence the name of this weird circuit - "voltage-inversion negative impedance converter" (VNIC). It is interesting that now the virtual ground will move inside R1.

---

So once the humble electrical circuit is understood, it can be used to explain the more complex op-amp circuits. This is a powerful approach to intuitively understanding and explaining electronic circuits.

Comment: Neatly drawn diagram.

Comment: @ FrontRanger, Thanks! It would be nice if the corners were rounded ... but I was in a hurry and it became quite angular. Also the night light is terrible but tomorrow I will shoot it again...

Answer (score 4):

Just rearrange it a bit and it will be a lot easier:

[image]

All this stuff is wired in parallel, and with zero-resistance perfect ideal wires (which exist only in theory) so it is possible to put them in any order you like without actually changing anything besides readability.

With real copper wires there would be a small voltage drop along the way, so this is of course an approximation.